# dynamic content type

Tags: wcf, rest

i want to make a single wcf rest function which can return any content type (text-html / applicaiton-javascript and even gif .

what should be the signature of the function ( the return type )

what should be the format of the service ?like [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

P.S: i cant make any new method due to the format of my javascript calls and due to the limitation on wcf rest since it doesnot differentiate b/w calls based on the parameter part(after the ? ) of the query string .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the return type Stream.

Comment: This always returns the `application/octet-stream` content type. Is there a way to dynamically specify a value that more accurately describes the stream's contents?